# Nav not overlapping elements as it should

Tags: html, css

I have a nav with five buttons that display on top of each other. I have set the height set to the height of just one of the buttons and my overflow set to visible. The four buttons display on top of the div I have below my nav like they should. However, these buttons move elements within my div down and don't display on top of them. If you're confused, you can see what I mean with my JSFiddle link at the bottom of this post. 
What I want is for the last four buttons in my nav to overlap anything below it without offsetting it.

Here's my html:

```
<body>
    <div id="mobile"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul id='nav'>
            <li><a href="index.html"><icon><img src="images/home-icon.png"></icon>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="skillsets.html"><icon><img src="images/skills-icon.png"></icon>Skillsets</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html"><icon><img src="images/gallery-icon.png"></icon>Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><icon><img src="images/about-icon.png"></icon>About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" style='border-right:1px solid black;'><icon><img src="images/contact-icon.png"></icon>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
/***
Style sheet template for all web sites
****/
/*Fix display for old browsers*/
header, nav, footer, section, article, aside{
    display:block;
}
/*Reset Browser Defaults*/
body, div, header, nav, footer, section, article, aside, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/*CSS properties for document*/
header{
    padding:2%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 0 0px 0;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}
header h1{
    font-size:64px;
}
header div#mobile{
    height:0px;
    display:block;
}
#logo_div{
    min-height:84%;
    min-width:26%;
    max-height:84%;
    max-width:26%;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:1%;
}
#logo_div img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    float:right;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
img.logo{
    z-index:99;
    border:2px solid black;
}
header img.logo:hover {
    opacity: .8 !important;
    border:2px solid darkgray;
}
nav{
    background-color:rgba(195, 165, 131, .0);
    text-align:justify;
    margin:auto;
    width:94%;
    height:27px;
    overflow:visible;
    float:none;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    position:relative;
    font:Calibri, 'Asul', serif, "Times New Roman", Times;
    font-size:.7em;
    -moz-box-sizing:borderbox;
    -webkit-box-sizing:borderbox;
    box-sizing:borderbox;
    z-index:10;
}
nav ul{
    height:27px;
    overflow:visible;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
nav a{
    width:100%;
    height:27px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -wbkit- box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid #d4b873;
    background: #d6ba65;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#8c7738), to(#d6ba65));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8c7738, #d6ba65);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8c7738, #d6ba65);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8c7738, #d6ba65);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8c7738, #d6ba65);
    padding:0;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    text-align:left;
    -moz-box-sizing:borderbox;
    -webkit-box-sizing:borderbox;
    box-sizing:borderbox;
    border:none;
}
nav a:hover{
   background: #785a28;
   color: #ccc;
}
nav a:active{
    border-top-color: #5c441b;
   background: #5c441b;
}
icon{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:27px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
icon img{
    width:60%;
    margin:20%;
}
#main{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    margin:auto;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:justify;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -wbkit- box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
div#main img{
    width:320px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
#main h1{
    background-color:red;   
}
#main h2{
    background-color:green;
    margin:5px 10px -5px 4px;
    color:#444;
}
div#main h3{
    font-size:16px; 
}
#main p{
    background-color:blue;
    margin:10px 2%;
    font-size:14px;
}
#main ul li{
    list-style-type:disc;
    margin:0px 0px 4px 36px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#main ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4t45/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were looking to keep the nav in the same position as your original fiddle, apply the position absolute to the ul element and not the nav element. you would also need to set a width to the ul element.

```
    nav ul{
    height:27px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATfry/)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want an element to overlap another element, a few things have to be true:

1. The overlapping element (in this case, the nav tag) needs to have `position: absolute;`
2. The parent of the overlapping element needs to have `position: relative;`

Fixed up [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mUJF/)

Comment: Their position is really messed up now. Isn't there some way I could achieve my goal without taking the nav out of the document flow?

Comment: No, there's no way that I am aware of. If you prefer to have the navbar line up with your div#main, move the nav element inside of it and change div#main to position: relative. That will make aligning the nav easier.